# Select statement to grab data from a Netezza database and insert into a SQL Server database (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, netezza

I'm using SSIS to grab data from a Netezza db and inserting into SQL Server db. I have the queries working, and the first 2 queries use a data flow task to grab from Netezza (based on an `ID_NUMBER`) and inserted into SQL Server.

I have 15 different `ID_NUMBER`s to run against, and I want to run them one at a time, but I don't want to hard code the `ID_NUMBER` into the SQL statement each time I want to run a different `ID_NUMBER`.

Is there a way I can loop through each `ID_NUMBER` without hardcoding them in the SQL Statement?

Comment: each time you have to specify `ID_NUMBER`? or you are extracting this ID_NUMBER from a table before processing??

Comment: SELECT ID_NUMBER FROM table WHERE ID_NUMBER = 'S12345'.   Is there a way just to loop through each ID_NUMBER individually? Like pass them in through an array or something?

Comment: you are selecting ID_NUMBER from a table, then you need to loop over the results and perform a dataflow task for each ID_NUMBER?

Comment: All the data is then inserted into SQL Server, and subsequent queries are used to process all of the data. I have to do it for 15 different IDs. I could just run one ID at a time, but I'd like to have one run, when that is finished, have run automatically.

Comment: i think that it is clear right now, i will try to provide an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok...Thank you so much.

Comment: you have to use an Execute SQLment and store IDs in a result set, Then use a For each loop container to loop over them, in the Dataflow task use SQL command from variable as source and the variable must be built as expression.

Comment: i will provide more details in a while

Comment: i think this link is what you are looking for, if yes give me a feedback to write an answer https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/

Comment: I will work with this and see what I can do. I will let you know of my results. Thank you so much Hadi!

Comment: Yes you can loop based on id' but it depends where these id's come from? Typed in by a person? in a table? In an excel document?

Comment: They are coming from a table. I'm pulling data from several different tables in one sql statement. In my WHERE CLAUSE in that sql statement, it says WHERE ID_NUMBER = 'S01234'.   So it is only pulling data on that ID_NUMBER.  After the first select statement, that data is inserted into SQL Server. I then have several 'execute sql tasks' chained together to process the data into a final table. I could run it on all ID_NUMBER's at once, but that not what i need. I need to do it on one ID_NUMBER at a time. Once one run is finish, I want it to start another until all ID's have been Looped through.

Comment: In that case, @Hadi's link is exactly what you want

Comment: @Russtopher anything new?

Comment: Stuck now because I'm using an ODBC connection and not OLEDB. ODBC data source doesnt have a parameters button in the Source Editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 1 Using ODBC Source

*Based on your comments you are using ODBC source*

In ODBC you cannot use parameters *(same logic in link provided)*, you have to assign an expression to the SqlCommand Property of the `ODBC Source`

1. Click on the DataFlow Task
2. In the Properties Tab *(press F4 to show it)* go to expressions
3. Assign a similar expression to `[ODBC Source].[SqlCommand]` property

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [id] = " + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::id]
   ```
4. Click on the DataFlow Task and change the `Delay Validation` property to `True`

---

## Use Execute SQL Task + Foreach Loop Container

1. You have to use an Execute SQL Statement and store IDs in a result set.
2. Then use a For each loop container to loop over IDs
3. Inside the foreach Loop Container add a DataFlow Task
4. In the Dataflow task use SQL command from variable as source and the variable must be built as expression

*For a Step-by-Step Tutorial you can refer to the following Link:*

- [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/)

Comment: Stuck now because I'm using an ODBC connection and not OLEDB. ODBC data source doesnt have a parameters button in the Source Editor.

Comment: you have to use expressions, refer to the link above

Comment: in expression you have to use the following logic `"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [id] = " + @[User::id]`

Comment: just click on the dataflow task, in the properties tab, go to expressions, and assign the expression to `[ODBC Source].[SqlCommand]` property

Comment: @Russtopher i will be waiting for your feedback

Comment: getting this error on my expression   The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_I4" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Comment: add a casting function `"SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE [id] = " + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::id]`

Comment: Hadi, you are a genius! I've learned more from you here on Stackoverflow than I did in the 2 SQL classes I took at my University. Thank you so much!